# AngularJS - Event After $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I don't know how to do this,

but i have draggable item that could be placed on any location in a canvas,

every time this draggable change location the `$scope.arrowDraggableDetail` is being updated about the x and y position of this draggable also the `$scope.arrowDraggableDetail` is being $watch

```
.directive('arrowDraggable',['$timeout',function($timeout){

  return function(scope, element, attr){  
    $timeout(function(){
       scope.$watch('arrowDraggableDetail', function(newValue, oldValue) { 
          if(newValue ){
             ***CALLING API FOR UPDATE ***
          }
      }, true);
    });
  }

}])
```

what I need to do is to save the updated location of the draggable.

my problem is every time I drag the item I'm calling the api multiple times since`$scope.arrowDraggableDetail` value is changing frequently.

could anyone help me what is the best practice in this?

Comment: i asked a similar question recently. the technique is called debouncing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589322/only-run-a-javascript-function-if-it-is-not-run-again-after-a-set-amount-of-time

Comment: it will do and that was good way , but is there any function available for angularjs for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a debounce service in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320015/how-to-write-a-debounce-service-in-angularjs)